# Excel Find a cell where the sum in row is greater than the criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need some elegant way, (not like the one in the screenshots), to make the sum of all cells in one row and to find the moment where it goes over some specific value. When it finds that cell where the sum is greater, I need that cell to be identified and used for further purpose. 
On the example you can see what formula does, but this formula needs to be extended for each new data, so it is impossible to maintain like this.

[image: Example in Excel]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1513741/edit) to include the formula you have. A new screen cap allowing us to identify columns and rows would also be useful. also, what does " i need that cell to be identified and used for further purpose" mean, exactly? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This will probably require vba to simplfy.  One can reproduce your outcome with the following array formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX(C2:G2,0,MATCH(B3,MMULT(C3:G3,CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:E),{1;0;0;0;0},{1;1;0;0;0},{1;1;1;0;0},{1;1;1;1;0},{1;1;1;1;1})))+1),"Error")` using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter to confirm.  But that is not any shorter or expandable than your formula.

Comment: In the last row, how is INV5 greater than 3000?

Comment: @BruceWayne He is examining the sum of the preceding cells.  So `SUM(C8:G8)` > 3000 but `SUM(C8:F8)` is not.

Comment: I have add new picture in original post with more details. @Scott, you are right, when i have more then 100 columns, this formula will also get complicated. Do you have VBA solution? I will try to explain what i need this for. For example i purchase goods, and every delivery of quantity is represented in new Column. Row are types of product. Column B is representing how much i sold until give moment. So i should now in moment of sales which purchase invoice/date represented in column i am consuming. Sorry if didn't explain properly.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I find it to be more difficult to solve problems like this with tables where you are adding columns as you add data. It's much easier to normalize the data (i.e. stack the invoice quantities and products) first, then do the calculation on the stacked data.

I normalized a couple of rows from your data (just used paste special/transpose) so there was one row for each product/invoice/quantity.

I put the number criteria in a different table, then used VLOOKUP to add the number criteria to each row in the main table.

The main data table and the criteria table then looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFPvX.png)

Next I referred to [this post](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/03/31/create-running-totals-in-power-query/) to create a running sum calculation on the main table using PowerQuery.

The M function fnRunSum is defined like this:

```
(tbl as table, sumcolumn as text, rowindex as number, product as number) =>
let
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(tbl, each ([Product] = product)),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [ID] <= rowindex),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{{sumcolumn, "Temp"}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {}, {{"RunningTotal", each List.Sum([Temp]), type number}}),
   RunningTotal = Record.Field(#"Grouped Rows"{0},"RunningTotal")
in
    RunningTotal
```

After successfully creating the running sum, I added a conditional column to indicate whether the running sum on a row was above the criteria for that row. If it was, I flagged that row with a 1 and otherwise with a zero.

The output query definition:

```
let
    Source = reference_values,
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "RunSum", each fnRunSum(Source,"Quantity",[ID],[Product])),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "RunSumGreaterThanCriteria", each if [RunSum] > [Number Criteria] then 1 else 0)
in
    #"Added Conditional Column"
```

I then loaded the results of the query onto a sheet called "output". That data looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhrRR.png).

I then used MINIFS to get the minimum index of all of the 1-flagged rows for the product I was interested in. The MINIFS formula looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zQcF.png).

Finally, I wanted the "First Invoice Past Criteria" to refresh when any data was changed or added. To make that work, the query "output" needed to refresh when anything on the main sheet was changed. So I added this to the VBA behind the main sheet, which I had called "data":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    wsOutput.ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub
```